# After parsin json date result is NaN.NaN.NaN

Tags: jquery, json

I'm getting json datetime object as `/Date(1346996934000)/` and I'm adviced to convert this date like this

```
"aoColumns": [
{
    "sName": "JoinDate",
    "fnRender" : function(obj, val)
    {
        var dx = new Date(parseInt(val.substr(6)));
        var dd = dx.getDate();
        var mm = dx.getMonth() + 1;
        var yy = dx.getFullYear();

        if (dd <= 9)
        {
            dd = "0" + dd;
        }
        if (mm <= 9) {
            mm = "0" + mm;
        }
        return dd + "." + mm + "." + yy;
    }
}
]
```

but the final result is that I'm getting date as `NaN.NaN.NaN` ?
What can be a problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given sample date string works fine. You might not be getting the correct data in some record. Check it here.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/9dbCb/)**

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
var dx = new Date();
```

instead of

```
var dx = new Date(parseInt(val.substr(6)));
```

Comment: I should be using val variable since it hold my datetime property. With dx = new Date() display is fine 15.09.2012 but it's useless :)